# Twitter on Android

Tags: android, android-twitter

I am using `twitter4j` in my Android app. I have done so much research, but I am unable to signout programmaticaly from the account by this API.

The rest of the things are doing well. But how do I signout, so that the session will clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Twitter4j` is stateless thus requires no logging out.  See:

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/5957722d596e269c/c2956d43a46b31b5